# Nested properties syntax in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have nested object, defined in xaml.
For example, I had a code like this (`utils:HotkeyCommand` is my MarkupExtension class in code-behind):

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem>
  <dxb:BarButtonItem.Command>
    <utils:HotkeyCommand />
  </dxb:BarButtonItem.Command>
</dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

which looked rather clumsy, so I decided to rewrite it in the following way (and this worked fine):

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem Command="{utils:HotkeyCommand}" />
```

After that, I want to define some properties in my original code:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem>
  <dxb:BarButtonItem.Command>
    <utils:HotkeyCommand CanExecuteNotifier="{StaticResource GeneralEnabled}" Executed="test" Gesture="Ctrl+N" />
  </dxb:BarButtonItem.Command>
</dxb:BarButtonItem>
```

How can I re-write this code to a single line in the same manner?

I want to get something like following (but it doesn't compile). Are there any rules, that can be used to transorm one notation to the second one?

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem Command="{utils:HotkeyCommand CanExecuteNotifier={StaticResource GeneralEnabled}, Executed={test}, Gesture={Ctrl+N}}" />
```

Comment: This should be possible with a custom Markup Extension. You can start reading about Markup Extensions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747254.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it working with the help of x0r's answer *(where has it gone?)*

```
 <dxb:BarButtonItem Command="{utils:HotkeyCommand {StaticResource GeneralEnabled}, Executed=test, Gesture=Ctrl+N}" />
```

In addition to removing brackets I also had to change:

1. Change `Executed` from event to a property holding a delegate
2. To make possible using HotkeyCommand from a resource, I had to create a constructor in MarkupExtension with a parameter, as described [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/nested-markup-extension-bug)